# how to increase innodb_buffer_pool_size in windows command line

Tags: mysql

I was trying to create a table in MySQL, then got error 1206 (total number of locks exceeds lock table size).

I understand I need to increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. (The current setting is about 100m)
and my dataset is quite large.

The table I intended to create should return more than 1 million rows with lots of textual returns.
I am a historian and not very experienced in changing MySQL option files.

Comment: you can start here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your config file

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
```

Then restart the mysql service. You should ensure that your logfiles are of minimum 250M.

Since the variable `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is of type read-only, you have to set the value in the config file and restart the service.

Edit

Step by Step

1. Find the config file on the MySQL server. (my.cnf or my.ini)
2. Change the innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
3. Make sure your innodb_log_file_size=250M (minimum, log file size should be minimum 25% of buffer_pool)
4. Delete the old log files
5. Restart your service!

Comment: Thanks Kay, but how do I do it in command line? I have never changed option files in MySQL before. I'd really appreciate it if you can give me a step by step instruction? if that's not too much to ask. Thanks!

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size is a read only variable. It can only be set when the service starts.  You have to change the config file, the restart the service that is your only option.

Comment: Hi Kay sorry for being a pain. Am I right in assuming that I should do the following? 1, log into MySQL server. 2, open my.cnf in c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\ 3, edit the value of these two variables you mentioned 4, quit and restart mysql? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Changing the log file size to 25% of your buffer pool size is only a recommendation, and is not necessary for every site. And changing that variable may make this config change more complex. In MySQL 5.6 it's a bit easier because log files change size automatically on service startup, but on earlier versions (5.5 and earlier) you have to manually remove the old log files if you change the size.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks. I forgot that it was 5.1 and then manual removal is needed for the logfiles. I actaully have logfiles that are of same size as my innodo_buffer_pool_size (50G). Would you agree when I say if you have the space for set the log file size as big as the innodb_buffer_pool?

Comment: In 5.1, you can't have log files totaling more than 4GB (for example, two files of 2GB each), unless you use Percona Server. You probably don't need such large log files anyway. See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/11/21/how-to-calculate-a-good-innodb-log-file-size/

Answer (score -3):

Download MySQL workbench from MySQL.com, install on the server and it will help you doing edits in the config file